# Merging Extensive Changes with Git

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

On my two computers, I have been making changes simultaneously and so far It has worked fine. When I commit my changes, I pull and merge, and it usually works fine. Yesterday, I made some significant changes where I updated comments on almost all lines of a file on one computer and rearranged code on the other. Now, my local copy is 3 commits behind, and I have uncommitted changes that completely restructure the same code. Automerge fails, and when I try to manually merge, the markers are so complex, I can't even understand what's happening (it almost seems like code is completely missing).
I have come to the conclusion that I will have to start from what I have and manually re-make the changes from the last 3 commits.

Is there a way that I can manually make the equivalent changes to my local copy from the last 3 commits, and then commit it as if it was already merged (which I would have manually done)?

Basically, is there a way that I can commit without merging changes?

Comment: Perhaps you want `git pull --rebase`?

Comment: @vonbrand Is that safe to try it on my real repo (is it fully reversible)? I'm not sure how git will respond if I do this, but it's definitely worth a shot.

Comment: Don't believe me!!! Copy your complete repository to a safe place, and experiment there.

Comment: @vonbrand Will it only make changes to my local copy, or will it change it upstream? My changes are already both stashed and copied because I've been testing things.

Comment: I tried rebasing, and it failed with the same issues; the diff is so messed up that the code isn't even partially syntactically correct after it completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. I started a merge so that it added the various markers in the file ('=', '<' and '>'), and then pasted in my the contents from the version before I started the merge (but after I had made the changes). Once I had done that, I re-applied all the changes from the commits after my version, and committed that. A bit messy, but it worked.